# Go to matching cell in a row range based on drop down list

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a list of names in a row, A2 to AAS2, I also have a drop-down list containing all of those names. I would like some VBA code that when the list is changed excel jumps to the cell matching the item in the list. Could someone please help me with this? Thank you.

The names are just text, no named ranges.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Private Sub FindTicker()
   Dim MyVariable As String
   MyVariable = Range("L1").Value
   Application.Goto Reference:=Range(MyVariable)
End Sub
```

And Also

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address <> [L1].Address Then
   Exit Sub
Else
   JumpToCell

End If
End Sub

Sub JumpToCell()
Dim xRg, yRg As Range
Dim strAddress As String
strAddress = ""
Set yRg = Range("A2:AAS2")
For Each xRg In yRg
'MsgBox Cell.Value
    If xRg.Value = ActiveCell.Value Then
       strAddress = xRg.Address
    End If
Next
If strAddress = "" Then
   MsgBox "The Day You Selected in Cell D4 Was Not Found On " & ActiveSheet.Name, _
    vbInformation, "Ticker Finder"
   Exit Sub
Else
   Range(strAddress).Offset(0, 1).Select
End If
End Sub
```

When I tried using both of these when I changed the drop-down list nothing happened. No errors or anything.

Comment: Please edit in what you have attempted so far and what the issues you are having related to that code. Stack Overflow is for answering specific questions based on provided code, not for providing code.

Comment: "I have tried various solutions" - always helps to be a little bit more specific.  What is *one* thing that you tried, and exactly what happened when you tried that?

Comment: "I have a list of names in a row, A2 to AAS2" it can means various things e.g. named ranges. Not sure how your data look like.

Comment: I have edited my post with more information. I apologize for the lack of info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this and with some tweaks your code above could work but its a bit inefficient and more complicated than it needs to be. The simplest way would be to use the [Find method of the Range class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) to locate the cell:

Lets say your drop-down list of names is in cell A1 on sheet MySheet and the long list is in column C. Use the Find method to set a range variable to equal the first cell containing the item in cell A1.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("MySheet")

Set rng = ws.Range("C:C").Cells.Find(ws.Range("A1"), lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then ' the item was found
    rng.Select
Else
    MsgBox "This item is not in the list", vbInformation
End If
```